# Loop every row of subquery / Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have database like this:[image: db image]

I want to get Employee_conferenceDay for every Employee who exists in Conference with ID_conference = 206247. I did this:

```
SELECT Employee_conferenceDay From Employee Where ID_Employee = (Select ID_Employee From Conference Where ID_conference = 206247);
```

And I got this message:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

How I can do it this way to do sth with every row in subquery table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error because there are more than one employee in the `conference` table for `ID_conference = 206247`. Where `=` is to use to compare one value and when you have more than one value then you can use one of the following option.

first option is to use `EXISTS`

```
SELECT 
    Employee_conferenceDay 
From Employee e
Where EXISTS (
    select 
        ID_Employee 
    From Conference c
    Where e.ID_Employee = c.ID_Employee
    and ID_conference = 206247
);
```

second option is to use `IN`

```
SELECT 
    Employee_conferenceDay 
From Employee 
Where ID_Employee IN (
    Select 
        ID_Employee 
    From Conference 
    Where ID_conference = 206247
);
```